# Hide my primefaces version from the inspector

Tags: primefaces

In my project I am using PrimeFaces v6.0 and in my inspector you can see witch version that I use.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/Gparc-web/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery-plugins.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&amp;v=6.0&amp;v=6.0"></script>
```

Is there any trick to hide it?

Comment: Download the source of PrimeFaces and change it so it does not send the info. And check stackoverflow. Has been asked before

Comment: @Kukeltje can you please add more informations about this solution (or simplly the link of a stack question)

Comment: I don't have more information and currently too busy with other things to start searching for the duplicate (otherwise I would already have marked it as such). Using google helps too

Comment: Why do you want to hide the version from rendered URLs?

Comment: @JasperdeVries i want to rendred from the browser inspector

Comment: Again.. WHY do you want to hide it?

Comment: it's a security breach

Comment: Well, hiding the number will not solve it. One can easily determine the version by comparing sources. I would suggest to update to the latest version (6.2 at this moment).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47393100/how-to-hide-ln-and-v-parameters-for-primeface-resources

Comment: Cannot mark it as a duplicate due to a lack of an accepted or upvoted answer... (@JasperdeVries ;-))

Comment: Thanks, voted as a duplicate and edited/improved the other answer